# Changing item made with string in list

Tags: list, python-3.x, listitem

Let's suppose there's a list

```
List1 = ["*AS","tqttq244%@"]
```

I want to change the first item, `"*AS"` into `" AS"`(chang `*` into blank) not using a module (this is my first attempt at programming).

Is there any way to indicate the sequence of item in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings are immutable, meaning you have to build a new string and replace the old one.

```
List1 = ["*AS","tqttq244%@"]
new_item = " " + List1[0][1:]
List1[0] = new_item
```

`List1[0]` refers to the first item in the list (a zero-based index).

`List1[0][1:]` *slices* the string starting from index 1 (the 2nd character) until the end of the string.

`new_item` is constructed from a new first character and the rest of the original string skipping the first character.

Lists are mutable, so `List[0] = new_item` replaces the first item in the list.